# Vuforia AR core samples in Unity 2018.2.1 throws errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have Unity Editor version 2018.2.1 and Vuforia 7.2.23. If I download Vuforia core samples from assets store, I get the following error after importing the assets..
Here are the errors

```
Assets/Common/Scripts/CloudRecoEventHandler.cs(82,42): error CS1061: Type `Vuforia.ObjectTracker' does not contain a definition for `GetTargetFinder' and no extension method `GetTargetFinder' of type `Vuforia.ObjectTracker' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference
```

and this one

```
Assets/SamplesResources/SceneAssets/CloudReco/Scripts/CloudTrackableEventHandler.cs(37,61): error CS1061: Type `Vuforia.ObjectTracker' does not contain a definition for `GetTargetFinder' and no extension method `GetTargetFinder' of type `Vuforia.ObjectTracker' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Here is the screenshots[image]shot

When i run even if a comment those lines, it requires an upgrade of Vuforia 7.5 in which i downloaded but keeps on failing to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core samples in asset store don't support vuforia 7.2
You have to update vuforia manually (7.3+) or install Unity 2017.3.0 or higher